# How to print html elements in Java function?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am trying to print a selection list in a jsp file by calling ONE java function. I used System.out.println() but it only prints to the console when I called the function in jsp. Do you know what function I should use to achieve this goal?

Here is my code in my java function:

```
public static void displaySemester(Connection conn) throws SQLException{

Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT SEMESTER_NAME FROM SEMESTER_SCHEDULE_READER");
System.out.println("<select name =\"semester\">");
System.out.println("<option selected=\"selected\">Semester Select</option>");

while(rs.next())
{ 
     System.out.println("<option value=\"" + rs.getString(1) + "\">" + rs.getString(1) + "</option>");
}
System.out.println("</select><br><br>");

}
```

Comment: Make the method return a string and display it in the jsp file

Answer (score 0):

*I used System.out.println() but it only prints to the console*  Yes this will only print in the console

you need to call `out.println()` to print on the jsp page

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple solutions:

1. Your function returns an String, and then render the function's result in your JSP.
2. Pass a PageContext or a PageWriter to your function, and render the content to that object.
3. Implement your function as a custom JSP Tag, and use the tag inside your JSP, and PageContext will be provided to the custom tag by the container.

I believe the 3rd solution (creating a custom tag) is the best and the standard solution for your need.
Just read some documents about implementing custom tags, it's so easy to make one.